# Visual Studio error "Cannot run to the specified location"

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2017

[image]

Hello folks! Please, help! Any C# project I open and try to run using Ctrl+F10 this error pops up immediately. I tried to restart it, change the location of projects, repair, update Visual Studio, run as administrator nothing helps. looked up online, did not find anything. Every help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Check Output Path: *Right click your project* > *Properties* > *Compile* > Build output path